# Seeking WFS-T support in WPF/Silverlight application

Tags: wfs, software-recommendations, wpf, silverlight

I want to build a wpf/silverlight mapping application that enables real-time visualization of features in a map, and that allow different users to add features (points, polygons) to the map. My initial thought is to use WFS-T for this purpose, but unfortunately, I cannot find any free/cheap SDK that provide support for WFS-T within WPF.

Does anyone know about a free/cheap SDK that enable support for WFS-T within WPF applications?

Answer (score 0):

Check out:

1. [DeepEarth](http://deepearth.codeplex.com/)
2. [ESRI's ArcGIS API For Silverlight](http://resources.arcgis.com/content/arcgis-api-silverlightwpf/1.2/about) **

** You can download and use ESRI's Silverlight API for free.